# How should I remove the default Home item?

Tags: content-editor, site-configuration

I would like to delete the Home from master database. I can delete without any problem but I saw for example references in site configurations. Is there any other places where should I remove the references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question because I found out and tested the exact answer. Of course thank you for the answers. So here is the patch configuration what I used to remove all references to the default Home item from the default Sitecore configuration.

```
<sitecore>
    <settings>
        <setting name="DefaultItem">
            <patch:attribute name="value">/</patch:attribute>
        </setting>
    </settings>
    <sites>
        <site name="shell">
            <patch:attribute name="startItem">/</patch:attribute>
            <patch:attribute name="contentStartItem">/</patch:attribute>
        </site>
        <site name="modules_website">
            <patch:attribute name="startItem">/</patch:attribute>
        </site>
        <site name="website">
            <patch:attribute name="startItem">/</patch:attribute>
        </site>
    </sites>
</sitecore>
```

Answer (score 8):

It is safe to delete the default Home item. I have done so on many projects.

The only place where you need to update the reference is the default site definition:

```xml
<site 
  name="website"
  ...
  rootPath="/sitecore/content"
  startItem="/home"
  ... />
```

Some system sites, such as "shell" and "modules_website", also have references to the Home item. In most cases they won't be used, but it's still best to change them to point to an existing item.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not enough. Sitecore assemblies maybe use the startItem and contentStartItem, and if it's not existing maybe things can go wrong. For example the ```Sitecore.UiUtil``` ```GetHomeItem``` method uses and checking the length of it.

Comment: @TRNKTMS What are the circumstances in which this becomes a problem?

Comment: When I try implement this functionality - https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/adding-custom-javascript-and-stylesheets-in-the-content-editor/. To inject js/css into Content Editor. If I don't remove the contentStartItem for the ```shell``` site then it does not injecting the script. Strange but works like this...

Comment: @TRNKTMS: I never had issues with that... but makes sense to change it since the `shell` site has `master` set as the content database.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the default site definition and your custom site definition nodes in the config file. It must not include **/home** path as  *start path* and **master** as a *database*.

You don't need to care about *modules_website* as it is not using the *Master* database.

And regarding the **Sitecore.UIUtil.GetHomeItem** method, it won't create any issue. If it can't find the path */sitecore/content/Home* it will return the Item till */sitecore/content*.

Comment: ```Sitecore.UIUtil.GetHomeItem``` could issue if the ```contentStartItem``` is not an existing item because then it returns with null and it's checking the length of the setting - ```if (obj == null && site.ContentStartItem.Length > 0)```.