# Experience Editor stopped working after removing default Home node

Tags: configuration, experience-editor, site-configuration

I had removed the default home node, and created new home item. After this change, Experience Editor navigation stopped working(it is throwing "The layout for the requested document was not found" exception). How to point the experience button to new home node?

Comment: I guess the problem is that your new Home item doesn't have an assigned layout on the presentation details

Comment: If you go into desktop > Content Editor > click on your new home node. Then publish tab > Experience Editor. Does the editor work? I think your item just isn't editable because it doesn't have a layout on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Experience Editor starts on the home page of your current site. Based on the `startItem` from the  node for the current site.

> rootPath="/sitecore/content/sites/company" startItem="/Home"

If you go into Desktop > Content Editor > click on your new home node. Then Publish tab > Experience Editor. Does the editor work? Your item just isn't editable because it doesn't have a layout on it. If you fix that, it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you. My rootPath, and startItem are correctly pointed, and Experience editor button from publish tab works fine. It opens up the home page properly. Latter i had trouble from Launch pad Experience button, but i fixed that by doing some changes to the /sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/ContentEditing/ExperienceEditor. But unable to figure out how to fix the issue from start menu.

Comment: @GopikrishnaGujjula Have you removed the "website" site definition and using a new site definition for your main website site definition ?

Comment: Thank you, i found out the issue, i had removed the home node, but i have not updated the startitem in the "website" site definition. I am using different name (not the website) for my Site definition, that's where the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you to check these answer here - [How should I remove the default Home item?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2415/how-should-i-remove-the-default-home-item). It shows what you should change if you remove the  default Home item from master and web database.

Comment: Can you approvve the answer if it works?